Salesforce: How can I create a rule to override a field populated by a workflow?
I've set up a workflow that automatically populates a field with the current date whenever an account is updated to a specific status.
However, I also want the flexibility to override this field manually if necessary. How can I achieve this?
Salesforce Premier Success informed me that overriding a field populated by a workflow isn't possible without custom development work, which I would like to avoid.
Is there any workaround or alternative approach that would allow me to override this field manually without requiring custom code?

What do you mean by override? For certain users this automation shouldn't fire? Certain types of edits (say run it from UI but not if it's a Data Loader or nightly batch job)? Don't run if in same edit say a hidden checkbox is also set (and then silently clear the checkbox so it's ready for next time)?
